# C code to send simulated Alt-C to another App window using X11 calls and ioctl

Tags: linux, x11, c

I am writing a C program to allow me to send simulated keyboard input to another Application's window open on my desktop.
I need to be able to find the App window by name and get an id for it, and then set keyboard input focus to it.
I am using the X11 calls (not a third party WM).

I also need help simulating Alt-characters via `ioctl(tty, TIOCSTI, ???);` if that will work.

(Using Linux Mint 16 Petra with MATE Desktop, if that matters.)

Comment: Have you looked at the source of `wmctrl`? It can retrieve the name and ID. And look at the source of `xdotool` for sending keystrokes to applications. If you find Linux/Unix commandline app that does what you want, you can usually use it as an example on how to do these things.

Comment: If you are using X11 you don't want to mess with `ioctl()` - that is a completely different layer.

Comment: Thank you @Anthon. I have activating the other App working (learning from wmctrl).

Comment: Thank you @peterph. Now what should I use for the key sim?

Comment: @peterph, I have key simulation working by either of two methods, 1) using `XTestFakeKeyEvent()` and 2) using `XSendEvent()`. Neither seem very good because I have to use some combination of `XFlush()` or `XSync()` and `usleep()` values to keep from losing keys.